# Sketch text rendering is blurred

Tags: export, png, sketch-app, image-quality

After exporting screens from Sketch 3 to PNG, the text is blurred

Check out: [This Website](http://www.travelgap.io)

and see the three screens. It's almost not possible to read the screens. Even if you resize them it's not clear. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: Looks OK to me. If you want the text to be less 'blurred' or pixelated you need to export at a higher resolution.

Comment: You think its just the resolution? Because we export at 320px and its only 222px wide.

Comment: I had another look and the font rendering isn't great, but it isn't that bad either. I would export them at the correct size though to prevent any more distortions :)

Comment: As Cai said, it's always best to save graphics at the exact size you wish to display them, if possible.  It's not quite as noticeable with photos, but with graphics (things like text/icons/etc) the resizing can lead to quality loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are actually bigger than displayed in the website. This usually causes distortions. For best results resize the images in your graphic software and export them in the correct size.

The distortions are more visible due to the thin text in the images. In other types of images or with heavier font weights maybe this would be less perceptible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VIEW-CANVAS-SHOW PIXEL ON ZOOM (unticked it).

Comment: this doesn't affect exported assets

Comment: This answer deserves more votes

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!